# Generating a Class file from two XSD files using XSD tool

Tags: class, xsd

I have two XSD files
1. Transit.xsd
2. BusinessTypes.xsd

The Transit.xsd file consumes the BusinessTypes.xsd file and the BusinessTypes.xsd contains the all the complex types declared.

Kindly help me to convert these xsd files to classes using XSD Tool or any other. Thank you

Comment: We use [XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/) for this, which is now retired, though may be suitable if you just have a small project.

Comment: Other than the XML beans, Is there any other option to generate the classes from these two?

Comment: You know about JAXB, right?

Comment: I'm a .NET guy and I'm a bit close to it. I'm using the XSD.exe tool and when I typed xsd Transit.xsd from command prompt I got the error: Can only generate one of the classes or datasets

Comment: Yup! got it...Thank you..Import was not correct